# GLSL Passthrough Geometry Shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, opentk

I've been learning OpenGL (actually OpenTK) for a month or so, and I've started playing with geometry shaders. I originally wrote a much more complicated shader, which didn't work, so I've stripped everything down a simple passthrough shader, which still doesn't work.

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 420 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = transform * vec4(position, 1);
}
```

Geometry Shader:

```
#version 420 core

layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip) out;

void main()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i++)
    {
        gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position;

        EmitVertex();
    }

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 420 core

layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D diffuse;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

It should draw a white square in the bottom right of the window, and *without* the Geometry shader, it does, which is what I would expect. With the Geometry Shader, it renders nothing. Info logs show everything compiles and links fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: can't see any obvious errors, but did you check for shader compile and link errors?

Comment: Yeah, I checked after each compilation and after linking; no errors.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Weird, i thought i tried that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a `max_vertices` declaration for the output. The number must be a compile-time constant, and it defines the maximum number of vertices that will be written by a single invocation of the GS. It may be no larger than the implementation-defined limit of `MAX_GEOMETRY_OUTPUT_VERTICES`

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. Why doesn't that error show up in the compile/link infologs?

Comment: There must be some default value for this when not provided. Its strange but I think it should throw some error can you share code where you are compiling shaders?